# distcc failed to write: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: cygwin, distcc

When I use distcc, it fail with message below:

dcc_writex warning: failed to write: Transport endpoint is not connected

This is not happend at every time, does anybody has idea on this?

Comment: perhhaps you could share your code that is generating this error?

Comment: It's not easy to reproduce this error, you mean the code cause this problem? I think it should not matter with specific code.